# Mount and unmount using Azure ARM templates

Tags: azure, templates, azure-resource-manager

I am looking for a way to mount and unmount or create some symbolic links using azure ARM tempates. Any leads appreciated, could not find them :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do that directly. But you can always deploy script extension(s) or DSC extension(s) that would do the work for you. Script extension reference template (relevant part):

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
  "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'),'/', variables('extensionName'))]",
  "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
    "type": "CustomScript",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "settings": {
      "fileUris": "[split(parameters('fileUris'), ' ')]",
      "commandToExecute": "[parameters('commandToExecute')]"
    },
    "protectedSettings": {
      "storageAccountName": "[parameters('customScriptStorageAccountName')]",
      "storageAccountKey": "[parameters('customScriptStorageAccountKey')]"
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-customscript-extension-azure-storage-on-ubuntu